# How to configure jackson in spring dispatcher servlet?

Tags: json, spring

I want to send json data  to controller  in spring.How to configure jackson in dispatcher servlet and which jackson files to add in build path/lib?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the Jackson **dependency** first:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version> //your version//
</dependency>
```

You must add **@ResponseBody** statement in your code as well. For example:

```
public class JSONController {

    @RequestMapping(value="{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Shop getShopInJSON(@PathVariable String name) {

        Shop shop = new Shop();
        shop.setName(name);
        shop.setStaffName(new String[]{"mkyong1", "mkyong2"});
        return shop;
        }
  }
```

Also, add **`< mvc:annotation-driven />`** into your Spring XML configuration file.

You can find a full example of Jackson and Spring in this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-json-example/).

Comment: But my project is not a springmvc project rath web projecer its a dynamic web project.So I have only spring configuration file there.How to add jackson bean there?

Comment: Thank you Asier, im using spring dispatcher, and the freemarker response was driving me nuts. You've saved me so much time.